# How to pipe all the output of "ps" into a shell script for further processing?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ps

When I run this command:

```
ps aux|awk {'print $1,$2,$3,$11'}
```

I get a listing of the user, PID, CPU% and the actual command.
I want to pipe all those listings into a shell script to calculate the CPU% and if greater than, say 5, then to kill the process via the PID.

I tried piping it to a simple shell script, i.e.

```
ps aux|awk {'print $1,$2,$3,$11'} | ./myscript
```

where the content of my script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
# testing using positional parameters
echo "$1 $2 $3 $4"
```

But I get a blank output. Any idea how to do this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you use `awk`, you don't need an additional bash script. Also, it is a good idea to reduce the output of the `ps` command so you don't have to deal with extra information:

```
ps acxho user,pid,%cpu,cmd | awk '$3 > 5 {system("echo kill " $2)}'
```

#### Explanation

- The extra ps flags I use:

  - c: command only, no extra arguments
  - h: no header, good for scripting
  - o: output format. In this case, only output the user, PID, %CPU, and command
- The awk command compare the %CPU, which is the third column, with a threshold (5). If it is over the threshold, then issue the system command to kill that process.
- Note the *echo* in the command. Once you are certain the scripts works the way you like, then remove the word *echo* from the command to execute it for real.

Answer (score 3):

Your script needs to read its input

```
#!/bin/bash
while read a b c d; do
    echo $a $b
done
```

Comment: Thanks William, that worked. But it only read the first line of the ps command, i.e. USER PID %CPU COMMAND.

How can the script read the entire out of the ps?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get it using `xargs` command to pass the AWK output to your script as arguments:

```
ps aux|awk {'print $1,$2,$3,$11'} | xargs ./myscript
```

Some extra info about `xargs`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs

Comment: Cool,this works! As well as the tips about the 'read' command. However,I only get the first line from the ps aux, i.e:             

USER PID %CPU COMMAND. 

How do I get all output from ps aux|awk {'print $1,$2,$3,$11'} into my script?

Thanks!

Comment: If I were you, I would iterate through the lines (to sum their value) in the AWK script, it is easier. If you need some help, just let me know.

Comment: Here is an example to get the total % of CPU consumed using AWK: `ps aux | grep -v "%CPU" | awk 'BEGIN{cpu = 0.0;} {cpu = cpu + $3;} END{print "CPU: "cpu"%";}' -`

Comment: Hi Arutaku, thanks for the example. What I'm trying to do is to find the PID of a process where the %CPU is above a certain threshold, e.g. %CPU > 5

Is that possible with the AWK script?

Comment: I have just posted a new answer trying to solve your problem using AWK

Answer (score 1):

When piping input from one process to another in Linux (or POSIX-compliant systems) the output is not given as arguments to the receiving process. Instead, the standard output of the first process is piped into the standard input of the other process.

Because of this, your script cannot work. $1...$n accesses variables that have been passed as arguments to it. As there are none it won't display anything. Instead, you have to read the standard input into variables with the `read` command (as pointed out by William).

Answer (score 1):

The pipe '|' redirects the standard output of the left to the standard input of the right. In this case, the output of the ps goes to the input of awk, then the output of awk goes to the stdin of the script.
Therefore your scripts needs to read its STDIN.

```
#!/bin/bash
read var1 var2 var3 ...
```

Then you can do whatever you want with those variables.

More info, type in bash: *help read*

Answer (score 1):

If I well understood your problem, you want to kill every process that exceeds X% of the CPU (using `ps aux`).

Here is the solution using AWK:

```
ps aux | grep -v "%CPU" | awk '{if ($3 > XXX) { print "Killing process with PID "$2", called "$4", consuming "$3"% and launched by "$1; system( "kill -9 " $2 );}}' -
```

Where XXX is your threshold (% of CPU).

It also prints related info to the killed process, if it is not desired just remove the print statement.
You can add some filters like: do not remove root's process...

Comment: Wow ... that works perfectly! Thank you so much! Now I just need to learn some AWK to understand the cryptic commands :)

Any suggestions of a good beginners tutorials for awk? Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome ! AWK is very powerful to do this stuff. Maybe you could try: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html good luck !!

Comment: Thanks again! Appreciate your help very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting myscript in front like this:

```
./myscript `ps aux|awk {'print $1,$2,$3,$11'}`
```